# Tridion Workflow Error on EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE Stored Procedure When Restarting WF Activities

Tags: workflow, tridion, tridion-2011

I'm hitting an error whenever 2 or more instances of a workflow is **restarted**. We have suspended workflows during a network incident in our office(s). It was a script timeout that disrupted the process. I couldn't reproduce this timeout anymore so I attempted to restart the workflow activities to complete the process. However, when I restart more than 1 suspended activity, I get this error (the full log is farther below):

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ITEM_ID', table 'tridion_cm.dbo.ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Restarting activities and letting it finish one by one has no problem.

**Full Event Log:**

```
An error occurred while executing the Workflow script.
The Script Engine returned the following information:

SOURCE:

    Line = 0
    Column = 0
    Number = -2147220673
    Source = Component.Save
    Description =
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="8004033F" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Component (tcm:5-32795).]]>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4418</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:5-32795</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="true">CDATA[No data found. ETA_ITEMS, U Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ITEM_ID', table 'tridion_cm.dbo.ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false"><![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE".]]>
        <tcm:Token>EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,DbAsyncResult)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult,String,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Update(IdentifiableObjectData)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.UpdateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Component.Save</tcm:Location>
        </tcm:CallStack>
    </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

```xml
    HelpFile = 
    HelpContext = 1000440
caused by: Component.Save
and description:
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="8004033F" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Component (tcm:5-32795).]]>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4418</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:5-32795</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="true">CDATA[No data found. ETA_ITEMS, U Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ITEM_ID', table 'tridion_cm.dbo.ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false"><![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE".]]>
        <tcm:Token>EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,DbAsyncResult)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult,String,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Update(IdentifiableObjectData)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.UpdateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Component.Save</tcm:Location>
        </tcm:CallStack>
    </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

```xml
Source:
    LogScriptError
```

**Workflow Info**

The components are newly created by another application through BusinessConnector. It performs revision saves before finishing the activity. The objective of the WF is to

1. assign the necessary component links based on text values from the other system;
2. create a page;
3. and publish it to a target.

I know this could've been done better by other means but it is how it is right now, please bear with the implementation.

**Model / Schema**

```xml
Product
    - modelName (text)
    - categoryName (text)
    - categoryCL (component link)
    - statusName (text)
    - statusCL (component link)
    - blah1 (text)
    - blah2 (text)
    - blah3 (text)
    - blah4 (text)
```

**Automatic Activity Script:**

```vb
' COMPONENT WORKFLOW for PRODUCT SCHEMA (START)

' Load common functions
ExecuteGlobal oTDSE.GetObject("/webdav/200%20Design/Building%20Blocks/Library/Design/Workflow/Common/Workflow%20Functions.tbbs", 1).Content

' Initialize
Set objComp = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem()
Set oContentPub = objComp.Publication
Set oWebsitePub = oTDSE.GetObject(GetStagingLangPub("EN", "website1"), 1)
modelName = objComp.Fields.Item("modelName").Value.Item(1)

' Search and Assign component links based on some text fields from BC client
Set compListRowFilter = oTDSE.CreateListRowFilter()
Call compListRowFilter.SetCondition("ShowNewItems", TRUE)
Call compListRowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", 16)

' Assign the first component link (categoryCL)
categoryName = objComp.Fields.Item("categoryName").Value.Item(1)
Set categoryComp = GetObjectFromFolder(categoryName, oTDSE.GetObject(categoryFolderWebDav, 1), compListRowFilter)
If Not categoryComp is Nothing Then
    objComp.Fields.Item("categoryCL").Value.RemoveAll
    objComp.Fields.Item("categoryCL").Value.Add(categoryComp)
    Call objComp.Save(True)
Else
    Call SendNoObjectEmail("Category", categoryName, "categoryCL", GetEmailsFromGroup(oContentPub, categoryOwner), "")
End if

' Assign the second component link (statusCL)
statusName = objComp.Fields.Item("statusName").Value.Item(1)
Set statusComp = GetObjectFromFolder(statusName, oTDSE.GetObject(statusFolderWebDav, 1), compListRowFilter)
If Not statusComp is Nothing Then
    objComp.Fields.Item("statusCL").Value.RemoveAll
    objComp.Fields.Item("statusCL").Value.Add(statusComp)
    Call objComp.Save(True)
Else
    Call SendNoObjectEmail("Status", statusName, "statusCL", GetEmailsFromGroup(oContentPub, statusOwner), "")
End if

' Create a page with the component in WF
Set oPage = CreateDefaultPage(modelName, oWebSitePub, SaveToFolderWebDav, PageTemplateWebDav)
Call oPage.ComponentPresentations.Add(oWebSitePub, oTDSE.GetObject(ComponentTemplateWebDav, 1))
oPage.Save(True)

' Publish the page
....

' Send email
....

' Finish the Activity
Call CurrentWorkItem.ActivityInstance.FinishActivity("someMsg")

' COMPONENT WORKFLOW for PRODUCT SCHEMA (END)
```

I haven't zoomed in to where exactly it happens but I would assume it is either the categoryCL or statusCL's `objComp.Save(True)` line.

Comment: Is this automatic activity? If so, can you post your script, if no - when exactly does this happen?

Comment: Could you add details of the workflow activities, and the method/scripts you are using to start the workflow. Also please specify exactly when the error occurs

Comment: If you think you have hit a bug in the product, I suggest reporting your issue to SDL's Customer Support.

Comment: Perhaps, You could improve your question by providing more information  and some context in addition to the stack trace. It is extremely difficult to understand and provide any answers with not much context.

Comment: To all, I've added more info regarding my case. Please stop down-voting it. Thank you.

Comment: @user978511, yes, it is an automatic activity. I've updated the question with the script.

Comment: @ChrisSummers I've added the workflow description above. I hit the error when I restart 2 suspended instances, 1 of it fails with the SP error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm inclined to think that it is a bug. And I will report it to SDL support as soon as I get our support passwords reset.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are calling `Call objComp.Save(True)` - The "True" parameter forces a "CheckIn", as it means "Done Editing".

It looks like this can occur twice (i.e. If there is a statusCL and a categoryCL) whichmay be causing the problem. I would try changing the behavior so that you only the call `Save()` method at the end if a change has been made, and not saving it twice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is that you are trying to assign nulls as component links. Are you sure that you are not trying to link these 2 components one to another? It might be that the link you are trying to create is to new component in workflow (it has no checked-in version yet), hence you can't create link to it. Try adding some logging to your script, so we could see where exactly does it fail and what are the parameters.

And I agree with Frank that this exception is worth a defect report.

Comment: @Lanthe: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am getting the same issue and we are not using any workflows right now.